# Magento responsive

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd, mobile

I would like to use my existing Magento Template for Desktop (as it is not optimized) and want to buy a new one for Responsive. Is it possible, to have them separated? What would be the best way?

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by Magento admin. Go to `System > Configuration > General > Design -> Package and Theme sections`.

Click `Matched Expression` and this:

```
iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini
```

This settings will be use for detecting Mobile devices.

You can create New Package and Theme for mobile devices as shown below:

[image]

From above, 
create new Package at : `\app\design\frontend\mobile_package\`

and Theme at : `\app\design\frontend\mobile_package\mobile\`

Answer (score 0):

Goto `System->Configuration->General->Design` and add `exception` theme for particular user agent

For Example for `iPhone and Mobile`  add `iPhone|Mobile` in `Matched Expression` and add your theme for that useragent

click save and check with that particular user agent